Git LFS to handle .xgb files in a Data bricks notebook
I am trying to upload a model file object with an extension of .xgb from datarbricks notebook to a branch on my repo, I start with creating a blob object. Although I specified in the .gitattributes files in my repo that I want the LFS to handle .xgb files and pointed it towards that extension I keep getting this error. Can anyone please help with this? Thanks. File size is 89MB which shouldn't be big for LFS to handle, I thought the limit was 100 MB, then files need to be handled using LFS.

I Tried this exact same notebook with the same code with an .xgb blob object with a size of 54MB and it was created successfully. Any thoughts?
